# JavaFX: setHgrow(...) doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx, vbox, hbox

I couldn't get the Elements in my HBox to grow, so I downloaded the following example code from [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/LetonlyonecontrolgrowinaHBox.htm). It serves as a minimal not working example:

```
package fxtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Fxtest extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 250, Color.WHITE);

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        TextField field = new TextField();
        HBox.setHgrow(field, Priority.ALWAYS);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Search:"), field, new Button("Go"));


        root.getChildren().add(hbox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The result looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa0iK.png).

If I understand it correctly, the TextField should grow, shouldn't it?

My Java Version is 1.7.0_51

My JavaFX Version is 2.2.51-b13

Do you know why it isn't working/what I have to do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Why [HBox.setHgrow](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setHgrow%28javafx.scene.Node,%20javafx.scene.layout.Priority%29) doesn't work for you**

You use a [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) as the root node of your scene and groups are not resizable, so the group size does not adjust to the scene's size.

> A Group will take on the collective bounds of its children and is not
>   directly resizable.
>
> By default, a Group will "auto-size" its managed
>   resizable children to their preferred sizes during the layout pass

In general, you very rarely want to use a Group as the root node for a scene.

**How to Fix it**

Use only resizable nodes in your scene ([Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) subclasses or [Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html) subclasses).

**Sample**

Substitute your start method with the method below which removes the Group root node and instead makes the HBox the root node for the scene:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
    TextField field = new TextField();
    HBox.setHgrow(field, Priority.ALWAYS);
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
    hbox.getChildren().addAll(
        new Label("Search:"), field, new Button("Go")
    );
    hbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 600, 250, Color.WHITE);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Output of the sample after resizing the window (you can see that the search text field grows and shrinks to fit available space as requested):

[image: grow]

[image: shrink]

Comment: Fellow airheads: `Hbox.setHgrow` != `hbox.setHgrow`

Answer (score 4):

jewelsea provided the right answer for the given example; thanks for that!

It helped me figuring out a problem with similar symptoms but another root.
If you use ScrollPanes, you need to set

```
    scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
    scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
```

in order to get the desired growing effect.